Google Cloud Load Balancing: cannot select Google-managed SSL certificate
I'm planning the migration of our managed HAProxy instance to a GCP Global external Application Load Balancer. As we need to switch production traffic, we must have everything set up before switching DNSes. To accomplish this, we're preparing the SSL certificates.
According to Cert Docs:

Google-managed certificates are supported with the following load balancers:

Global external Application Load Balancer
Classic Application Load Balancer
External proxy Network Load Balancer (with a target SSL proxy)


We created a DNS authorization and activated it, then we created two certificates, a wildcard (*.somedomain.com) and a third level one (someapp.somedomain.com), and they're both marked as Active.

Sadly, when I create a new Global external Application Load Balancer, I'm unable to select any of those certs. I'm instead only allowed to pick Classic certs.
Unfortunately, Classic certs can be activated when the hostname matches the external DNS, and this requires a downtime we cannot afford.
Is there any limitation to my account, or did I misinterpret something on the docs? Why can't I select a DNS-authorized certificate for my load balancer?
A collateral question: SSL certificate documentation about types says:

Google-managed SSL certificates are certificates that Google Cloud obtains, manages, and renews automatically. Google-managed certificates are always Domain Validation (DV) certificates. They don't demonstrate the identity of an organization or individual associated with the certificate, and they don't support wildcard common names.

But, in reality, it's possible to create wildcard certs (see above).

Yes, you are correct.  As per the official GCP SSL Certificate documentation which you provided regarding wildcard certificates and existing PIT feature requests both misinterpret. (Limitation : The Internal HTTP(S) load balancer supports Global Access, but this feature is not supported on the GKE Internal Ingress).

Based on the above confusion, you can work with global SSL certificates on Classic Certificates. This would require downtime for hostname verification. Please note that this is a less desirable option, but it's the only immediate workaround available.

Thanks for the feedback, but it's not 100% clear to me. I'm right in what? Stating that I can generate wildcard certs? My main question is: why I cannot use the modern SSL certificates for the Load Balancers?

I was just testing a GCP load balancer, and it only shows classic certs in the drop-down list.  why can't I use the modern SSL certificates for the Load Balancers? Just checked network tier, it is on 'premium'.

@Sam seems only classic certs are usable with Load Balancer, at least that's what I got

Having exactly the same issue, did you find any solution ?

@JonathanChevalier I didn't use wildcard but normal Google-managed certs. I haven't tried raising an issue to support
